# How do I get a value from another component in my model?

Tags: angular

I'd like to set default values when instantiating a new object. I have a GlobalFunctions component which contains my global functions (surprise).
Usually I would create components this way but I have no idea how to create it in the models. This is what I have now:

```
import { GlobalFunctions } from '../components/shared/GlobalFunctions';

export class Order {
    constructor(private _GF: GlobalFunctions) { }

    Orderdate = <string>this._GF.getCurrentDate();
    DeliveryType = <string>null;
    ...
}
```

`_GF.getCurrentDate()` returns the date in `DD-MM-YYYY`-format.

When I do it like this it returns an error in the console: `error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`. Any ideas to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting your functions, so have you provided `GlobalFunctions` in `bootstrap(AppComponent, [...])` or a component decorator `@Component({ ... providers: [...]})`? :)

Comment: I certainly have. I think there's a problem with instantiating _GF in the constructor parameters, but I don't know how to work around that issue :/

Comment: Where are you importing the Order class?  do you need it to be injectable?

Comment: Order is a modelclass. When I retrieve something from the database, it should automatically map the properties. But when I create a new Order-object, it should have default values. At the moment I'm importing it in a component when I create a new order

Comment: Do you have a code snippet for where you are creating/populating the Order() object?

Comment: I'm just creating it in the component constructor with `this.order = new Order()`. But `new Order()` is red underlined. I think it is because in the order constructor `_GF: GlobalFunctions` is defined. In a component this setup works, but I don't know how to do it in a model.

Comment: Yeah, new Order() will fail because you're not sending over an instance of GlobalFunctions.  You could remove GlobalFunctions from the constructor parameters, and instead create a new instance of GlobalFunctions inside the constructor. e.g. this._GF = new GlobalFunctions().  Or you do something like this.order = new Order(new GlobalFunctions())